# Subtracting Binary Numbers with one and two's complement

Tags: binary

An example:

$01001 - 11010 = -10001 = -17$

one's complement: $00101$
two's complement: $00110$

so the above statement should evaluate the same as:

$01001 + 00101 = 01110$ (inverting it) $= 10001$ which is almost the same except $+17$ rather than $-17$ so I use the first bit as a sign bit then its just $-1.$

using the two's complement is not much better:

$01001 + 00110 = 01111 = 15$ which again is nowhere near the $-17$.

What in the world am I doing wrong$?$  This seems so simple but I can't get it to work.

Comment: i think this is not a mathematica question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always manage to confuse myself with this process since it is not done manually too often, so refer to this handy [*algorithmic like approach*](http://worldclassprogramme.com/1's-2's-Complement.php). In both cases, the number we are subtracting is larger in magnitude.

**$1's$ Complement:**

1. Determine the $1's$ complement of the larger number: $00101$
2. Add the $1's$ complement to the smaller number: $01001 + 00101 = 01110$
3. There is no carry. The result has the opposite sign from the answer and is the $1's$ complement of the answer.
4. Change the sign and take the $1's$ complement of the result to get the final answer: $-10001$

This is $-17$.

**$2's$ Complement:**

1. Determine the $2's$ complement of the larger number: $00110$
2. Add the $2's$ complement to the smaller number: $01001 + 00110 = 01111$
3. There is no carry from the left-most column. The result is in $2's$ complement form and is negative.
4. Change the sign and take the $2's$ complement of the result to get the final answer: $-10001$

This is $-17$.

Comment: Thank you! I think what I was missing is that after you do everything you have to find the complement again to get the final answer.

Comment: You are quite welcome and I also forget those little tidbits so like using approaches that are clearly mapped out. I would recommend trying example for various sizes that hit all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Binary format works:

```
2^^01001 - 2^^11010
```

> -17

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question.  I already know the answer.  I want to know what I am doing wrong with the complement methods...

Comment: `2^^00101 - 2^^10110 = -17`,  not `2^^00101 - 2^^00110 = -1`

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all.

Comment: Change 0 for 1 and 1 for 0, `2^^` is Mathematica notation for binary